# How to change encoding of UserAgent in HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, unicode, user-agent

Today I met a problem with the encoding of UserAgent when I tried to use HttpWebRequest to post a request.

Normally, UserAgent consists of Latin letters and punctuation. However, I need to simulate web requests of an iOS app whose UA contains some Unicode (specifically Chinese) characters.

Using Fiddler to get the raw request, I found that the app gave used Unicode encoding in its UA. I couldn't POST it in C#; I got this error:

> You may not try to send Unicode in UserAgent. But it is really important for my project. Now I can simulate the request of App without the bytes of UA.

How can I change UA encoding?

Answer (score 2):

according to the standards ([rfc 2616 (http/1.1), sec 2.2, 3.8. 14.43](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) and [rfc 2047 (mime, part 3), sec 4, 5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)), you can't use any other encoding but iso-8859-1 for any http header field like user-agent.

however, you can apply the encoding scheme of rfc 2047 to map unicode string onto 8859-1 - strings; in a nutshell, you wrap your text with a charset identifier and substitute the unicode codepoints by the hex values of the octet sequence in their respective encoding.

example:

`User-Agent: Million-€-Browser` becomes `User-Agent: =?utf-8?q?Million-=e2=82=ac-Browser?=`, with `e2 82 ac` being the utf-8 octet sequence of the euro symbol.